# Gamecenter registers only first score sent from app

Tags: ios7, xamarin, game-center

Using xamarin 4.2.2 and building universal app.

I've been using this code for a while, but this is the first app I develop with ios 7 sdk

submitting scores in sandbox works as designed, where every new submission updates the score on game center leaderboard.
After publishing the app, and not using sandbox anymore, it appears only the first score is registered. There are no exceptions or errors, it just fails to update the score to the new one.

What's troubling is that it works perfectly if I go back in sandbox, so there's no way for me to debug it...

```
GKScore scoreReporter = new GKScore (leaderboard_id); // leaderboard_id is string
 scoreReporter.Value = score; // score is a int64
 scoreReporter.ReportScore (new GKNotificationHandler ((error) => {
                                if(error != null){
...raise alert
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, most stupid question / solution.

Leaderboard was low to high, instead of high to low. So only lowest score gets recorded...